# Dynamic JComboBox Size

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, dynamic, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox` that takes up too much room my GUI because of the long `String`s it contains. I only need to see their full length while making a selection. So, I'd like the `JComboBox` to be full size only then and shorter otherwise.

The following code seems to work. But, since I'm very much a Java newbie, I'm just wondering if there's a better or more standard way of doing this.

Thanks.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class DynamicJComboBox{
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(250, 100);

        JComboBox box = new JComboBox();
        box.addItem("Really Long Line Number One");
        box.addItem("Really Long Line Number Two");
        box.addItem("Really Long Line Number Three");
        box.addItem("Really Long Line Number Four");
        box.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
        box.addPopupMenuListener (new PopupMenuListener() {
            @Override
            public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                box.setSize(100,30);
            }
            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                box.setSize(200,30);    
            }
        });
        frame.add(box);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception exc) {}

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        createAndShowGUI();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The following code seems to work

Not really because you change the size of the combo box which would cause the combo box to overwrite any component display on the right of it. Also, the combo box arrow is drawn in the middle of the combo box.

Check out [Combo Box Popup](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/). This solution also uses a PopupMenuListener (so you were on the right track) but it only increases the width of the popup when it is displayed, not the combo box as well.

Comment: Funny, the problems that you mentioned did not happen in my actual GUI, just in the pared-down version that I posted here. But, I switched over to your suggestion anyway since it's more flexible. Thanks.

Comment: Just for my own learning experience, why does `popupMenuWillBecomeVisible` reschedule the `customizePopup` method to run on the Swing event thread? I would have thought `popupMenuWillBecomeVisible` is already running on this thread.

Comment: @GregValvo, Yes, it is running on the EDT. I don't remember the specifics, in this case, but maybe the problem was that the size was not yet known because the menu wasn't actually visible, so I needed to make sure the code was executed after sizes had been determined so I could override them. The invokeLater() adds the custom code to the end of the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Small hack to get pop up menu size bigger enough to show items even though the combo box size could be smaller

Source: http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/make_jcombobox_popup_wide_enough

```
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.util.Vector;

    import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
    import javax.swing.JComboBox;

    public class ComboBoxFullMenu<E> extends JComboBox<E> {

        public ComboBoxFullMenu(E[] items) {
            super(items);
            addActionListener(this);
        }

        public ComboBoxFullMenu(Vector<E> items) {
            super(items);
            addActionListener(this);
        }

        public ComboBoxFullMenu(ComboBoxModel<E> aModel) {
            super(aModel);
            addActionListener(this);
        }

        /**
         * Small hack to get pop up menu size bigger enough to show items even though
         * the combo box size could be smaller
         * */
        private boolean layingOut = false; 

        @Override
        public void doLayout(){ 
            try{ 
                layingOut = true; 
                super.doLayout(); 
            }finally{ 
                layingOut = false; 
            } 
        } 

        @Override
        public Dimension getSize(){ 
            Dimension dim = super.getSize(); 
            if ( !layingOut ) {
                dim.width = Math.max(dim.width, getPreferredSize().width);
            }
            return dim; 
        }
    }
```